# schtasks set "If the tasks is not scheduled to run again, delete it after:"

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I've googled and seached super user for this but haven't found anything. I wan to set the option "If the tasks is not scheduled to run again, delete it after:" using schtasks, or if thats not possible if you know another way to set that option in a scheduled task.

Edit: This needs to be via command line

Comment: Sorry should have made it clear, it needs to be via command line.

Comment: So what commands are you using to create a task already?

Comment: I'm using schtasks.exe

Comment: So you want to edit already existing tasks? Or you want to create a task with this particular flag?

Comment: Either is fine, I have to create tasks regularly so it'll be easier to do it while its being created, although I have no objection to modifying it after the fact if that is the only option.